# how to auto submit a form by a random user?

Tags: php, sql, drupal

im using Drupal,

im comparing two fields, when the fields are true I want the form being viewed to submit, but by a different user to the one viewing the form.

I get list of users by uid, maybe using the following code

```
$submitter = db_result(db_query('SELECT uid FROM {bidtable} WHERE nid = %d', $node->nid ORDER BY rand ));
```

then I compare 2 values

`if ($match < $bcd) {}`

but i need some code which will submit the form, and set the author or submitter to a random user from my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the INSERT ... SELECT query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-select-to-insert-records